# Where is Node.js installed? Why can't I see /usr/local/bin/node?

Tags: path, node.js

I installed node and made sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in my `$PATH`.

I checked for node install version and location

```
[~]$node -v

v10.15.1


[~]$which node

/usr/local/bin/node
```

Why, when I cd into  `/usr/local/bin/`, is there nothing there?

I'm on MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.2. I installed node version 10.15.1 using the installer downloaded from nodejs.org, and using the default options in the installer.

Here are the notes i took from the installer:

```
Welcome to the Node JS Installer -> This package will install: 

• Node.js v10.15.1 to /usr/local/bin/node 
• npm v6.4.1 to /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Select the disk where you want to install nodejs -> MacintoshHD

(clicked install) ...

```
This package has installed: 

• Node.js v10.15.1 to /usr/local/bin/node 
• npm v6.4.1 to /usr/local/bin/npm 

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.
```

Checked `/usr/local/bin` is in `$PATH`.

```
[~]$echo $PATH

:~/usr:bin:~/bin:usr/local/bin:usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

---

But the when I check where node is installed:

```
[~]$which node

/usr/local/bin/node

[~]$cd usr/local/bin/node

-bash: cd: usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. Such as what OS you are on, what version of Node you installed, what instructions you followed to install node and such.

Answer (score 4):

The command

```
root@user:# whereis npm
```

should return the path to your node.js installation.
It returns something like this:

```
/usr/bin/npm
```

Comment: If you use the command `whereis node` you'll get where node is located. Good suggestion

Comment: I use NVM so it returned something different, but this was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I was looking in the wrong directory. Here is the explanation.

```
usr/local/bin/
```

is not the same as

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

The wrong one:

```
[~]$cd usr/local/bin
[bin]$ls -a
.       ..      .DS_Store
[bin]$cd /usr/local/bin/node
-bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/node: Not a directory
```

The right one:

```
[bin]$cd /usr/local/bin
```

Exists! Then

```
[bin]$ls -a
```

And node is indeed there.

From the mac terminal, there is the difference between `usr` and `/usr`.

Comment: Stack policy is that answers should be answers and not questions, but since this would probably get shot down if separate, see [wikipedia on Absolute and relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths)

Comment: The difference is that "usr/" is relative and "/usr" is absolute. If you enter "cd usr/", it's looking for a directory named 'usr' in your current location. Adding the slash first tells it to start at the root of the volume.